# Cannot logrotate hourly by cron

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have the following entry in /etc/crontab

`47 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb_dumps &> /tmp/errrot`

The line is run because the /tmp/errrot if created (empty), however logrotate does nothing.

If I run the line on command line out of cron, it works fine and it outputs to /tmp/errrot.

The file /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb_dumps has:

```
/home/backups/alldbs.sql.gz {

rotate 48
create 640 root adm
notifempty
nocreate
}
```

Packages are:

```
cronie-1.4.11-19.el7.x86_64
cronie-anacron-1.4.11-19.el7.x86_64
```

OS is CentOS 7

What should I modify to run logrotate hourly?

Note: I've tried even putting the line in a separate file in /etc/cron.d and even setting a custom path for logrotate as in [How to execute logrotate every hour](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2018/07/11/how-to-execute-logrotate-every-hour/). None of those approaches work.

Comment: It's a small point, but `&>` (as a redirection) is a bashism - are you sure cron is running jobs with bash (rather than POSIX `sh`)? if not, it may explain why the error file is empty

Comment: I sure running bash, it was a selinux issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found it was a selinux issue, but it was somewhat hidden, so I run:

`semodule --disable_dontaudit --build`

then I've found those denials, I've created selinux modules for exception and applied and now it works fine.

Then, I've run:

`semodule --build`